# images and js is not working but works outside the main folder what can i do any suggestion

Tags: javascript, html, image, src

images and Js is not working but works outside the main folder what can i do any suggestion this is html problem how to include the source

`<script type="text/javascript"  src="assest/js/jquery.js">` for JS or Jquery 
`<img src="assest/images/logo.jpg" alt="Logo">`  this is also not working

[image: Files hierarchy]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably misspeled something. 
In the image you uploaded you wrote "assest" instead of "assets".
It looks like you're trying to reach `logo.jpg` but you wrote you have `logo.png`